# How can I match spaces with a regexp in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I expect the code below to echo "yes", but it does not. For some reason it won't match the single quote. Why?

```
str="{templateUrl: '}"
regexp="templateUrl:[\s]*'"

if [[ $str =~ $regexp ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Replace:

```
regexp="templateUrl:[\s]*'"
```

With:

```
regexp="templateUrl:[[:space:]]*'"
```

According to `man bash`, the `=~` operator supports "extended regular expressions" as defined in `man 3 regex`.  `man 3 regex` says it supports the POSIX standard and refers the reader to `man 7 regex`.  The POSIX standard supports `[:space:]` as the character class for whitespace.

The [GNU `bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) documents the supported character classes as follows:

> Within ‘[’ and ‘]’, character classes can be specified using the
>   syntax [:*class*:], where *class* is one of the following classes defined
>   in the POSIX standard:
>
> alnum   alpha   ascii   blank   cntrl   digit   graph   lower print
>   punct   space   upper   word    xdigit

The only mention of `\s` that I found in the GNU `bash` documentation was for an unrelated use in prompts, such as `PS1`, not in regular expressions.

#### The Meaning of `*`

`[[:space:]]` will match *exactly one* white space character.  `[[:space:]]*` will match *zero or more* white space characters.

#### The Difference Between `space` and `blank`

[POSIX regular expressions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) offer two classes of whitespace: `[[:space:]]` and `[[:blank:]]`:

- `[[:blank:]]` means space and tab.  This makes it similar to: `[ \t]`.
- `[[:space:]]`,  in addition to space and tab, includes newline, linefeed, formfeed, and vertical tab. This makes it similar to: `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`.

A key advantage of using character classes is that they are safe for unicode fonts.

Comment: Note that `[:space:]` means all whitespace, including carriage returns and newlines; while `[:blank:]` means "horizontal" whitespace (spaces and tabs) -- http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: For just matching a literal space, you can also escape it with a backslash, i.e.: `regexp="templateUrl:\ *'"`

Comment: @ChristophThiede Yes, that's true.  Actually, though, you don't need the backslash.  `regexp="templateUrl: *'"` also works.  In either case, of course, this limits the regular expression to matching an actual ASCII blank.  The other whitespace characters that may be recognized by `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]` are not matched.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the square brackets in the regular expression:

```
regexp="templateUrl:\s*'"
```

With the square brackets present, the `\s` inside gets interpreted literally as matching either the `\` or `s` characters, but your intent is clearly to match against the white space character class for which `\s` is shorthand (and therefore no square brackets needed).

```
$ uname -a
Linux noname 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it. 
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ cat test.sh
str="{templateUrl: '}" 
regexp="templateUrl:\s*'"

if [[ $str =~ $regexp ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
$ bash test.sh
yes
```

Comment: Did you test it? Using `regexp="templateUrl:\s*'"` still echo's "no" for me.

Comment: I ran your script verbatim - and it echoed `yes` for me.  I'm running on a Linux Mint 17 box.  I'll update the answer to reflect as such.

Comment: You are right, I switched to a Mac and got different results from my Linux box.  It appears that bash on OS X (at least the flavors that you and I have) defaults to strict POSIX notation - you should go with the answers from @John1024 or heemayl

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="{templateUrl: '}"
regexp="templateUrl:[[:space:]]*'"

if [[ $str =~ $regexp ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

If you want to match zero or more whitespaces the `*` needs to added after `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: `*` seems to be needed.

Comment: In my `GNU bash, version 4.2.25` it is not being needed.

Comment: I see. Ugh, this is so annoying.

Comment: @crzrcn The `*` is needed if you want to match zero or more spaces.  It is not needed if you want to match _exactly_ one space.

Comment: Yup, that's why I said that it seems to be needed. I want to match zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way that work, if you want only the space from the space character class.

```
#!/bin/bash
str="{templateUrl: '}"
if [[ $str =~ templateUrl:" "*"'" ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
 echo "no"
fi
```

credit to Malak Younes.