# Match url with regex containing forward slash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I used following shell script for check regex.

```
#!/bin/bash
urlPattern='/demo/([^\s]+)/'
#echo $urlPattern
if [[ "/demo/akash/" =~ $urlPattern ]];then
  echo "match"
else
echo "not match"
fi
```

givin me as result as "not match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` with `-P` to understand Perl regexps (like yours seems to be) and with `-q` to suppress its output and just use its exit value:

```
#!/bin/bash
urlPattern='/demo/([^\s]+)/'
if grep -qP "$urlPattern" <<< "/demo/akash/"; then
  echo "match"
else
  echo "not match"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Regexes in bash don't understand `\s` and similar constructs. You can use `[:space:]`, though:

```
urlPattern='/demo/([^[:space:]]+)/'
```

Comment: I dont wont to change my regex is there any other solution ?

Comment: Switch to a different language that understands the regex, e.g. Perl.

Comment: `[:space:]` is the only solution, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256178/how-can-i-match-spaces-with-a-regexp-in-bash

Comment: `<soapbox>`
Response to [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)'s suggestion to use `[:space:]` was "I dont wont to change my regex is there any other solution". Without more context there are several, but no way to know which would make you happy. You should really offer more information.
`</soapbox>`