# Deleting leading spaces is not working in Bash

Tags: string, bash, removing-whitespace, parameter-expansion

I have a string in Bash which may or may not start with any number of leading spaces, e.g.

```
"  foo bar baz"
" foo bar baz"
"foo bar baz"
```

I want to delete the first instance of "foo" from the string, and any leading spaces (there may not be any).

Following the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256178/how-can-i-match-spaces-with-a-regexp-in-bash), I have tried the following:

```
str=" foo bar baz"
regex="[[:space:]]*foo"
echo "${str#$regex}"
echo "${str#[[:space:]]*foo}"
```

If str has **one or more** leading spaces, then it will return the result I want, which is `_bar baz` (underscore = leading space). If the string has *no* leading spaces, it won't do anything and will return `foo bar baz`. Both 'echoes' return the same results here.

My understanding is that using `*` after `[[:space:]]` should match **zero** or more instances of [[:space:]], not one or more. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

**EDITS**

@Raman - I've tried the following, and they also don't work:

```
echo "${str#[[:space:]]?foo}"
echo "${str#?([[:space:]])foo}"
echo "${str#*([[:space:]])foo}"
```

All three solutions will not delete 'foo' whether or not there is a trailing space. The only solution that kind of works is the one I posted with the asterisk - it will delete 'foo' when there is a trailing space, but not when there isn't.

Comment: @RamanSailopal The [docs at GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) say that `?` matches zero or one occurrence, and `*` matches zero or more occurrences. I tried it anyway and it didn't work - will update the question.

Comment: `and they also don't work:` enable extglob...

Comment: What's wrong with just `${str#*foo}`?

Comment: @oguzismail in the case `str=oguzfoo`, I guess op doesn't want a match.

Comment: @Lou: just to make sure this isn't an XY-problem: are you trying to split your string at spaces? if that's the case, you should instead use: `read -ra ary -d '' < <(printf '%s\0' "$str")`, and you'll have the tokens in the array `ary`.

Comment: @Lou, alright, good luck then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing to do is to use parameter expansions (with extended globs) as follows:

```
# Make sure extglob is enabled
shopt -s extglob

str=" foo bar baz"
echo "${str##*([[:space:]])}"
```

This uses the extended glob `*([[:space:]])`, and the `##` parameter expansion (greedy match).

**Edit.** Since your pattern has the suffix `foo`, you don't need to use greedy match:

```
echo "${str#*([[:space:]])foo}"
```

is enough.

**Note.** you can put `foo` in a variable too, but just be careful, you'll have to quote it:

```
pattern=foo
echo "${str#*([[:space:]])"$pattern"}"
```

will work. You have to quote it in case the expansion of `pattern` contains glob characters. For example when `pattern="foo[1]"`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Why do you use the longest match instead of the shortest match out of interest?

Comment: @Lou: Otherwise it will only remove the first space. But now I realize you also have `foo` in your pattern, so `echo "${str#*([[:space:]])foo}"` would be enough. I've edited the answer (and also added a remark about putting the pattern in a variable).

Comment: Okay, I now seem to be having a different problem. My Bash code will only remove the substring in a variable when it's unquoted. E.g. if I have a `str="foo bar"`, and a `re="*([[:space:]])"foo"*([[:space:]])"`, then if I `echo "${str#$re}"`, it will happily delete `foo` and leave `_bar` (with leading space). But if I do `echo "${str#"$re"}"` with quotes around the regex expression, it won't. What's the deal with quoting Regex variables? I feel like I've missed something else here.

Comment: @Lou: 1. you don't need to quote the token `foo` in the `re`: this is enough: `re="*([[:space:]])foo*([[:space:]])"`. 2. The pattern _must not be quoted!_ actually, quotes are here to _prevent_ interpretation of the pattern as a pattern! hence: `echo "${str#$re}"` (without quotes for `$re`) is correct.

Comment: @Lou: so you only want to quote when there's a variable that might contain a pattern that you don't want to be interpreted as a pattern (e.g., something obtained from user input). Btw, do you want to remove that leading space? (if yes, you need to use greedy match with `"${str##$re}"`.

And yes, quotes are a bit awkward to grok at the beginning…

Comment: In this case I actually want to preserve the leading space, so that works great, but it's good to know. Thanks for the clarification! I think I got confused when you said that you have to quote the pattern - looking back I realise you meant that the pattern variable should be quoted when instantiated, but not when used in the parameter expansion. Is that right?

Comment: @Lou: not quite :) The pattern variable should be quoted _in the parameter expansion **only if you don't want it to be interpreted as a pattern.**_ Here's an extremely simple example you can try: `str="foo bar"; pattern="*"`. (The fact we're using quotes here is irrelevant). Without quotes: `echo "${str#$pattern}"` you'll get `oo bar`, because `str` matches the _pattern_ `f*`. But with quotes: `echo "${str#"$pattern"}"`, you'll get `foo bar`, since `str` doesn't match the _verbatim content_ of `pattern` which is `f*`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thanks for explaining it so clearly :)

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is that using * after [[:space:]] should match zero or more instances of [[:space:]], not one or more

That's wrong.

> What am I missing

That [glob](https://linux.die.net/man/7/glob) is not [regex](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html). In *regex* `*` matches zero or more preceding characters or groups. In glob `*` matches anything. It's the same as for filename expansion, think along `ls [[:space:]]*foo`.

You can use extended bash glob and do:

```
shopt -s extglob
str=' foo bar baz'
echo "${str#*([[:space:]])foo}"
```

To do anything more complicated, actually use a regex.

```
str=' foo bar baz';
[[ $str =~ ^[[:space:]]*foo(.*) ]];
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: Ah brilliant! I did not know about the difference between regexes and globs before. Now it works, and the string trims correctly. Cheers :).

Comment: Out of interest though, why get the longest match from the start `##`? The shortest match `#` also works.

Comment: Och, I think you wanted to remove the spaces behind `foo` too.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a real regex match, you should be using a real regex match:

```
$: [[ "$str" =~ [[:space:]]*(.*) ]]
$: echo "[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]"
[foo  bar       baz]
```

A more pedestrian approach would be to skip the quotes.

```
$: echo "[$str]"
[ foo bar baz]
$: new=$( echo $str )
$: echo "[$new]"
[foo bar baz]
```

Be aware that this opens you up to all sorts of messes in any more complex situations.
It breaks if you wanted to preserve more than a single consecutive space between values, or a tab instead of just a quote, etc.

```
$: str=' foo  bar'$'\t''baz';
$: echo "[$str]"
[ foo  bar      baz]
$: new=$( echo $str )
$: echo "[$new]"
[foo bar baz]
```

It can cause other sorts of havoc too, but it's good to know the trick for the cases when it's appropriate.

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do - I only want to trim leading spaces from the front of the string plus a given word, not from all words in the string.

Comment: Which is why I warned about it. The first match solution is the better approach