# Extract Regex Capture Group in Script

Tags: sed, grep, csh

I am writing a CSH script and attempting to extract text from a source string given a key.

```
!/bin/csh -f
set source = "Smurfs\n\tPapa\nStar Trek\n\tRenegades\n\tStar Wars\n\tThe Empire Strikes Back\n"
set toFind = "Star Trek"
set regex = "$toFind[\s]*?(.*?)[\s]*?"
set match = `expr $source : $regex`
echo $match
```

The above code does not work, so I am missing something. I tried placing "Star Trek" directory inside rather than a variable. I should see `Regenages` as the answer. Had I put "Star Wars" as instead of "Star Trek", I should have seen `The Empire Strikes Back`.

Google search showed a possible solution using grep, such as

```
match = `grep -Po '<something>' <<< $source
```

I did not know what to put for `<something>`, nor am I an expert in grep.

In the real code, I am reading text from a file. I just simplified things here.

Thoughts?

Comment: grep is for matching, sed is able to edit the stream, this is a good introduction: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html - also has examples on how to combine with shell scripts including csh.

Comment: @mandy8055 Your bash script returns "Star Trek" and not "Renegades", so directly as written no. That being said, I am open to a bash solution, though would still leave my original question up, as I am curious if a solution is possible in csh.

Comment: *"Thoughts?"*  ... Your reg-ex looks very much like perl reg-ex (but I have no experience with that) . SO, if that is a perl-reg ex, you can be sure that unless you have a version of `expr` that supports perl-regex, that will never work. BUT now I am reading your initial problem descrip, *"attempting to extract text from a source string given a key."*. ?? key/values. Why are you using such an  unhelpful solution? why not `key[str]="value"` or even just `myKey=Renegades` ? Ah, *" I am reading text from a file."* it might have helped to have that near the top of your Q. .....

Comment: Following on, as you say *". I just simplified things here."* I would rather spend my `csh` time on converting 2 lines of input into variable assignments, but it seems  you have to deal with spaces in your var-names, so nix to `Star Trek="Renegade"` )-; . Doing quick research, I don't see that `csh` can do `arr[key]="value"` arrays, only `set arr = (one two three)`, which are then referenced as `echo $arr[1] $arr[3]` etc. If you're processing a file with an extenal utility, the `sed` is good, but `awk` will give you much more understandable code. Busy now, so that's all I can come up with now.

Comment: Back the the perl-regex thing, There is a small set of perl-regexps special syntax that can be rewritten in long-hand basic regexp. I have to believe that the `expr` utility only uses basic regexs, but it's not documented in `GNU coreutils 8.30` version of `man expr`. ( maybe in `info '(coreutils) expr invocation'`? ). You do know that using `csh` is shell scripting w one hand timed behind your back? OK as a learning challenge, but jobs/work, you'll do much better getting good at `bash` or `zsh` or something even newer (fish?) (`man grep` search for ERE is the best I can find). Good luck.

Comment: Regarding "I am writing a CSH script" - don't do it. [google csh why not](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution uses a file for the source, so is:

```
set valueCapture=`cat /mypath/filename | grep -A1 "${tofind}" | grep -v "${tofind}" | xargs`
```

The code to find a capture value from a string should be (did not test it):

```
set valueCapture=`cat $source | grep -A1 "${tofind}" | grep -v "${tofind}" | xargs`
```

In both cases, the what I wish to find is:

set tofind='asdf1@wxyz2'

The `xargs` part trims off whitespace.

Comment: That's doing partial regexp matching across whole lines when you almostcertainly should be doing whole-line or whole-field string matching, and it'd fail if the same target string appeared in both lines.

Comment: Also, [UUoC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award). Drop the `cat file` and just `grep -A1 "${tofind}" file. From a string you might use `echo "$source"`, but not `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not a literal answer to my question, as I asked the question for csh, however I wrote a solution using bash.

Match [Regex Capture Groups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251013/bash-regex-capture-group)

Match Whitespace
[How can I match spaces with a regexp in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256178/how-can-i-match-spaces-with-a-regexp-in-bash)

I used [Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) to debug.

```
mystring1='  asdf1@wxyz2  @@a!s#d@f@@  asdf2@wxyz2 b!t#e@g '

tofind='asdf1@wxyz2'
regex="${tofind}[[:space:]]*([.!@\#a-zA-Z0-9]+)"

[[ $mystring1 =~ $regex ]]

echo $'\n'
echo $'\n'
echo '***********************'
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo '***********************'
```

Comment: `mystring1='  asdf1@wxyz2  @@a!s#d@f@@  asdf2@wxyz2 b!t#e@g '` is not in the same newlines+tabs separated format as the text in your question, `set source = "Smurfs\n\tPapa\nStar Trek\n\tRenegades\n\tStar Wars\n\tThe Empire Strikes Back\n"`. This is a possible answer to a different question than the one you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said your real input is in a file, here's the file your `printf` outputs:

```
$ cat file
Smurfs
        Papa
Star Trek
        Renegades
        Star Wars
        The Empire Strikes Back
```

and here's how to match and print the strings you want from it:

```
$ awk -v tgt='Star Trek' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} $0==tgt{n=NR+1} NR==n' file
Renegades
```

```
$ awk -v tgt='Star Wars' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} $0==tgt{n=NR+1} NR==n' file
The Empire Strikes Back
```

See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline can do it, though it isn't as good as Ed's single process `awk`.

```
$: toFind="Star Wars"; echo "$source" |  grep -EA1 "$toFind" | tail -1
        The Empire Strikes Back

$: toFind="Star Trek"; echo "$source" |  grep -EA1 "$toFind" | tail -1
        Renegades

$: echo "$source">file; toFind="Star Trek"; grep -EA1 "$toFind" file | tail -1
        Renegades
```

A `sed` would work.

```
$: toFind="Star Trek"; sed -n "/$toFind/{n
                                         p}" file # should work with any version
        Renegades

$: toFind="Star Wars"; sed -n "/$toFind/{n;p}" file # semicolon is GNU
        The Empire Strikes Back
```

All of these are probably worth refining your regex.

```
$: toFind="Star"; sed -n "/$toFind/{n;p}" file
        Renegades
        The Empire Strikes Back

$: toFind="Star"; sed -n "/^$toFind$/{n;p}" file

$: toFind="Star Trek"; sed -n "/^$toFind$/{n;p}" file
        Renegades

$: toFind="Star Wars"; sed -n "/^$toFind$/{n;p}" file # fails because of the leading tab
```

That last one might mean you have to allow the first one.
Test your logic.